# Drupal 7 Ubercart, custom blocks displayed in external article based on product

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, drupal-taxonomy, drupal-blocks

I'm currently creating an ecommerce site using Drupal and the Ubercart module,  for each product I need to have the option to display an article (blog/story) that relates to that specific product. I also need the article pages to display related products. I initially intended to do this via taxonomy, i.e. using tags to link the products and articles and creating blocks with the necessary filters but I thought that this would become messy as the product catalog grows.  I know that i could just create a custom field  and write my own sql queries to grab the relevant content and display it but i was wondering if there's any built in functionality (or modules) that would enable me to link an an article to a product during the product creation process. Like a drop down menu on the add product screen where i could select and relevant article.

I've looked over many module specs and forum posts but can't seem to find a solution to this kind of problem.

Any pointers would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [References](http://drupal.org/project/references) module for referencing to other nodes or users.

Install this module, then add module type of this = Reference.

**Notes**:

- It also support Views for selecting, so you got powerful of selecting needed nodes.
- For showing you can use Views, where set argument or filter to referenced field.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have added this module but cannot see what to do with it. The readme is very vague.

Comment: Managed to add the Reference field to the add product form, thanks. Now to find out how to pull the related data through into the referenced story! thank you